# Angularjs Bad Request with Spring+Jersey+Jackson

Tags: angularjs, api, post, jersey, jackson

i am trying to insert a row in a database table using a POST request, but i get BAD REQUEST error. 
This is my API

```
@POST
@Path("/insert")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Transactional
public Response setShop(Shop shop) throws Exception {
    daoShop.insertShop(shop);
    return Response.ok()
            .entity(shop)
            //.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
            .allow("OPTIONS")
            .build();
}

@OPTIONS
@Path("/insert")
public Response preflight(
    @HeaderParam("Access-Control-Request-Method") String requestMethod,
    @HeaderParam("Origin") String origin,
    @HeaderParam("Access-Control-Request-Headers") String requestHeaders) {
return Response
    .ok()
    //.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") // TODO replace with specific origin
    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, origin, Content-Type")
    .build();
}
```

and this is my piece of angular code trying to contact the mapped API:

```
var datas = {"id":1,"name":"InsertNegozio1", "logofile":"logo", "coverfile":"cover", "address":"via di qui", "postalCode":"popopo", "city":"Dubai", "country":"Krypton", "description":"vomito", "openSince":2015-11-14, "closingStart":2015-11-14, "closingEnd":2015-11-14, "phoneNumber":"0598621", "email":"aaa@ggg.it"};
//datas: JSON.stringify(datas);
$http({
    method : "POST",
    url : "http://localhost:8080/shop/insert",
    data : datas,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'}
}).then(function mySucces(response) {

}, function myError(response) {

});
```

I tried uncommenting the stringify row but it still gives me error..
The JSON has all the fields of the Shop object that should be mapped, so i don't understand why i get BAD REQUEST..

EDIT: no errors on java side logging, the server responds with bad request, this is what i can see on js console on chrome (note: the class is mapped on /shop, the method on /insert)

POST http://localhost:8080/shop/insert 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Could you please show us stack trace with this error? You can also open "developers tools" in your browser and check headers and POST data.

Comment: Hi, can't post the error right now (tonight i will i think) but i can say that there is no error evidence on java (server) side, i get evidence of the error angularjs side, opening the console in chrome (ctrl+shift+j)